# MongoDB how do I prevent duplicate name values only within certain embedded documents?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, duplicates, embedded, aggregate

I've made a database to store to do lists for different users. For efficiency, I've structured the data so that all the lists and tasks are stored as embedded documents inside each user object. So there's a user, then an embedded array of lists, then in each list an embedded array of tasks. I want my api to prevent duplicate task names in the same list, and duplicate list names for the same user.

I do my filtering operations by name because I don't trust targeting queries with indexes which can change whenever lists/tasks are added/removed, and I don't want to generate a unique ID for each embedded document. I already have duplicate prevention on the front end, but I plan on making this api accessible by other sources and eventually other developers. Is there a reliable way for the api to prevent duplicate names within those scopes?

I've heard it can be done with mongoose schemas, but I haven't seen any examples that are specific enough for my issue. All I've been using is mongoDB shell so I'd rather not switch everything to work with mongoose schemas unless it's going to be very beneficial overall.

Comment: Would something like `$addToSet` work for you? It won't let you push duplicate values into an array. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/